How do I clear or reset the word suggestion on Windows 10?
My problem: Whenever I type the the word ma in any typing input on Windows 10, it shows me suggestions which has the word mà (as in the picture), this is a Vietnamese word from the last user on my computer. Windows takes it as a commonly used word and keep repeating that suggestion to the preferred input language.
I tried:

Removing the default.dic file inside %AppData%\Microsoft\Spelling\ directory.
Switching to another keyboard preferred input language because I noticed that the word suggestion data are not shared across input languages (This solution actually get rid of those unnecessary word suggestions but I do not want to use this method, I want to stay on en-US input language).

My quesion: Are there any methods to remove all the word suggestions or somehow reset to default settings for my current prefererred input keyboard language to have a fresh word suggestion where I can start everything again?

@Gantendo I still want to use it but not with the old suggested words

(1) In Windows 11 I have in Settings > Privacy & security > Custom dictionary a button for "Clear your custom dictionary". I don't know if this is different than deleting default.dic. (2) In %localappdata%\Microsoft\input\my-language I found a file named userdict_v1.language-code.dat which you might try to move elsewhere.

I tried @harrymc method, seem like that did nothing
